# How do you copy one Excel cell into another?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If you try to copy paste a cell and place it within the contents of another in Microsoft Excel, you cannot.

What you must do is F2 to select cell contents, Select All, and then Copy. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Have you selected a source cell, hit CTRL+C, selected the destination cell, hit CTRL+V?

Comment: Try using Paste Special .. VALUES, instead of trying to paste the complete cell,, is any of those cells part of a merged cell?

Comment: Are the two cells in the same **worksheet** ?? ......... Are they in the same **workbook**??

Comment: "If you try to copy paste a cell and place it within the contents of another in Microsoft Excel, you cannot." This is false

Answer (score 0):

**No**. There is no 'easier' way. If you want to put the contents of A1 (e.g. `abc`) into the contents of B1 (e.g. `123456`) so that B1 will then contain `123abc456` then you have to use F2 (or double-click for 'In-Cell editing') to select and capture/copy the content from A1.

However, if the position of the content of the paste is static (i.e. doesn't change) then you could macro it. For example, if you wanted to put anything you type into a cell in column A as a new line (i.e. paragraph) to the content of the cell in column B in the same row, right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose *View Code* then paste this into the worksheet's code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        On Error GoTo bye
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range, b As String

        For Each t In Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target)

            b = vbNullString 

            If t.Offset(0, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then
                b = t.Offset(0, 1).Text & Chr(10)
            End If

            If t.Value <> vbNullString Then
                t.Offset(0, 1) = b & t.Text
            End If

        Next t

    End If

bye:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Anything you type into column A will appear at the end of the content in column B on the same row.

Comment: Thank you for a direct answer, and the script!

Answer (score 0):

1. Ctrl+C  -Copy the cell as usual
2. Ctrl+V  -Paste as usual
3. Ctrl (and let go, do not hold down for the next V)
4. V

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I end up with just "v" in the cell

Comment: That will happen if anything interrupts the input. It was a little tricky for me at first. Basically, this is the keyboard shortcut to Paste Special > Paste Values. A lot more details can be found here: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/10/20/excel-paste-special-shortcuts-features/

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest methods**

There are many methods to do the work simplest is which **you** are **used to comfortable and suits you**.

1. Click and select the Cell contents you want to copy
2. **Ways to Activate the Editing Mode of the cell**

   (1) Press F2 button from keyboard

   (2) double click on the cell

   (3) click on address bar and edit mode
3. **Ways to select the contents of the source cell**

(1) Ctr+A 
     (to select complete all contents of cell)

(2) click on Edit menu  Select all
         (to select complete all contents of cell)

(3) Select the part text only from mouse 
                   (for selecting part of content)

(4) Select by Pressing Shift + <- arrow key 
                  (for selecting part of content)

4. **Ways for Copying  the contents of a cell**

   (1)  Press Ctr +C from keyboard

   (2)  Select Edit Menu select Copy

   (3)  Right click Menu and select copy

   (4)  If new version then Select copy from Quick Menu
5. **Ways to Paste the contents on the destination Cell**

   (1) Take the Mouse Pointer on destination cell
      click on the destination cell

   (2) Activate the Editing Mode on Destination cell 
       Press F2 (many ways as described in Point 2)

   (3) click or move the Cursor to the place you want 
      to paste the content at last or in between of
      text

   (4)  Ways to Paste from clipboard

   ```
   (a) Press Ctr +V

   (b) right click menu and select paste

   (c) Go to edit Menu and paste

   (d) Select Paste from Quick menu 

   (e) select paste special Values from 
       Quick menu/ Edit Menu/ Right Click
   ```
6. Another way is to combine the content through formula  by  appending or converting text
7. Another way is to record a macro for these steps
   and create a button for the macro recorded
8. Another way is to create a VB Program coding as  described by **Jeeped**  in his answer

There **may be**  **many other more ways** may be there but it depends on you which way you feel it easy and  simplest  for  and suits you